# Given a real valued continuous function on a metric space, what set is its graph homeomorphic to?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity, real-numbers

> $X$ is any metric space.$$f:X\rightarrow \mathbb R$$ is a **continuous**  real valued function. The graph of the function is $$G=\{(x,f(x)):x\in X\}$$ This set $G$ is homeomorphic to
>
> $1.X$
>
> $2.\mathbb R$
>
> $3.X\times \mathbb R$
>
> $4. \mathbb R \times X$

Now **Option $1$** is true by the function $(x,f(x))\mapsto x$. right?

**Option $3$**  is not homeomorphic since surjectivity cannot be confirmed but an **embedding**  indeed by the homeomorphism between $G$  and $X\times f(X)$.

**Option $2$** is a similar case as option $3$ 'cause the function $(x,f(x))\mapsto f(x)$  would be a homeomorphism between $G$ and $f(X)$.

Now I'm not sure about **option $4$** Is mapping the first co-ordinate to the second one valid ? That is can I say $X\times \mathbb R$  and $\mathbb R \times X$  are homeomorphic by the function $(x,r)\mapsto (r,x)?$

Also, please point out if my other assertions are correct or wrong . Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, $G$ is homeomorphic to $X$, and you found the homeomorphism. Well done!

---

Option $2$ **may** be correct, but only if $X$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

---

Options $3$ and $4$ are clearly homeomorphic (you again found the correct function), so the answer to both will either be yes or no.

Now, since you already know that $G$ is homeomorphic to $X$, you can see that $G$ is homeomorphic to $X\times \mathbb R$ *if and only if* $X$ is also homeomorphic to $X\times\mathbb R$.Now, this **might** be true, but not if option $2$ is correct.

---

Summary: depending on what $X$ is, it is possible that

- Only option $1$ is correct
- Only options $1$ and $2$ are correct while $3$ and $4$ are incorrect.
- Options $1,3,4$ are all correct, $2$ is incorrect.

Comment: I'll just mention that there do exist spaces for which $X$ and $X \times \Bbb R$ are homeomorphic, for instance $X = \Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ with the product topology.

Comment: @Shalop Ah. I thought about that (even asked a question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946215/homeomorphism-between-x-and-x-times-mathbb-r) but I only could think of $X=\emptyset$ as an example.

Comment: Wel  considering that $X$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$  will the function $(x,f(x))\mapsto f(x)$  be an homeomorphism between $G$ and $X\times f(X)?$

Comment: @user118494 In general, no, because it isn't defined on the entire set $X\times f(X)$. For example, it is not defined on $(x, f(y))$ if $f(y)\neq f(x)$. So it is only defined on the entire set $X\times f(X)$ if $f$ is a *constant* function, making $f(X)$ a singleton --  in this case, it clearly *is* a homeomorphism.

Comment: What does the continuity of $f$ have to do here ?

Comment: @user118494 You need it to prove that the mapping you construct is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @5xum : I think I've got it all wrong. the proofs I did were all nonsense .

Comment: @user118494 You wouldn't be the first person that happened to :). Look at your mistakes, learn from them, and move on.