# Homeomorphism between $X$ and $X\times \mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology

This question comes as a result of me answering [The graph of a real valued continuous function on a metric space is homeomorphic to what set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946201/the-graph-of-a-real-valued-continuous-function-on-a-metric-space-is-homeomorphic/1946207#1946207) which got me thinking.

> Is it possible to have two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that $X\times Y$ is homeomorphic to $X$?

The answer to this question is clearly (correct me if I'm wrong) yes, since any set $X$, equipped with either the discrete or the trivial topology, is homeomorphic to $X\times X$.

---

So, the next question would be

> Is it possible to have a topological space $X$ such that $X\times \mathbb R$ is homeomorphic to $X$?

And here, taking $X=\emptyset$ gets us through. However, the question I **don't** know how to answer is

> Is it possible to have a nonempty topological space $X$ such that $X\times \mathbb R$ is homeomorphic to $X$?

I don't see an easy answer to this. The "simple" answers don't seem to work here, and I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. For instance $\Bbb R^\infty$.

Comment: right. Silly me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For a non-trivial example for the first Q (with $Y=X$): If $S$ is a non-empty space and $X$ is the Tychonoff product  of infinitely many copies of $S$ then $X$ is homeomorphic to $X\times X.$

Answer (score 3):

> The answer to this question is clearly (correct me if I'm wrong) yes, since any set $X$, equipped with either the discrete or the trivial topology, is homeomorphic to $X\times X$.

Let me answer that: if $X$ is finite and has at least two elements, then no matter what topology you choose, $X$ will never be homeomorphic to $X \times X$, simply because there isn't even a bijection between them (much less a homeomorphism). If $X$ is infinite, however, then there is a bijection $X \cong X \times X$, and this does induce a homeomorphism when $X$ is equipped with either the discrete or the trivial topology. Same if $X$ is either empty or a singleton.

Comment: I actually wanted to write "any infinite set $X$", so thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 2):

If $X = Y^\kappa$ is any infinite product of copies of $Y$, then $X \times Y \cong X$, and $X \times X \cong X$.

The Cantor space $\{0,1\}^\omega$ is such an example.